# cron "@reboot" schedule not executing network configuration script

Tags: scripting, cron

Version: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

In my crontab I have the following:

```
@reboot /home/<user>/startup.sh
```

Other output:

```
<user>@eveng-gcp-v3:~$ ls -la | grep start
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root           root            154 Dec  3 11:57 startup.sh
<user>@eveng-gcp-v3:~$ pwd
/home/<user>
```

Script:

```
<user>@eveng-gcp-v3:~$ cat startup.sh
ip address add 192.168.0.1/24 dev pnet9

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o pnet0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Those 3 commands are accurate and work as expected when running manually.

How can I ensure this runs on bootup?

Comment: @jcbermu has probably the right solution, you should always give it some time. 30 seconds are usually used. Also don't forget the `#!/bin/sh` in the script like @U. Windl said, to prevent unexpected problems. And maybe change the question title to specify that is an interface problem :)

Comment: What user's crontab are you running your script from? To be able to perform those operations, I'm assuming that you would have to be root.

Comment: If it "is an interface problem", why does the OP write so? What are the symptoms of "not working as expected"?

Comment: Are you certain it _did not run_, or could it have run but _failed to do what it was supposed to do_?  Those two scenarios are _very_ different.

Answer (score 1):

The network interfaces are not ready when the cron script is being executed. Delay it with:

```
@reboot sleep [time in seconds] && /home/<user>/startup.sh
```

Comment: That is probably the solution. 30 seconds are usually used to ensure it has enough time :)

Comment: I would be rather surprised if network interfaces being down would prevent a cron command from being *started*.

Comment: "**Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup**" suggests the command is not being executed at all, so https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/772746/320598 is hardly helpful.

Comment: @U.Windl The cron daemon outputs that message whenever it re-reads the cron schedules and finds a `@reboot` job (and it's not reading them because it just started after a reboot). It re-reads the schedules whenever they have been updated. The existence of that message in the log means nothing.

Comment: OK, so the OP has to review the logs again.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt that you can execute your script, because it lacks the "[shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)".
Add `#!/bin/sh` (or your favorite shell).

Also you should have looked in to syslog, or `cron`'s log, or `root`'s mailbox for error messages.

Comment: So I checked the logs and see this:

(CRON) INFO (Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)

How do I make it system startup?!

Comment: Did you boot your system, or did you just start cron? Two possible solutions: (1) cron is broken in Ubuntu (https://serverfault.com/q/1089535/407952), or (2) you are trying to run a user job as @reboot (https://askubuntu.com/a/863268/955948) -- It seems your "**in my crontab**" refers to a user's crontab; maybe edit your question to make it more clear *where exactly your crontab file is*.

Comment: Yes it is my user crontab.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that I was using my own user's crontab and regular users cannot run `@reboot` jobs. I used root's crontab (`sudo crontab -e`) instead and it worked as expected!

Thanks everyone!